# Supremum of set and multiple upper bounds definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm wrapping my head around the definition of upper bounds and supremum. Following https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Upper_Bound_of_Set :

Let $(S, \preceq)$ be an ordered set. Let $T$ be a subset of $S$.

An upper bound for $T$ (in $S$) is an element $M \in S$ such that:

$\forall t \in T: t \preceq M$

That is, $M$ succeeds every element of $T$.

- So there is a set, some ordering of it, and the largest element of the subset is the upper bound

Now following https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Supremum_of_Set :

Let $(S, \preceq)$ be an ordered set. Let $T \subseteq S$.

An element $c \in S$ is the supremum of $T$ in $S$ if and only if:

1. $c$ is an upper bound of $T$ in $S$
2. $c \preceq d$ for all upper bounds $d$ of $T$ in $S$.

- While 1) makes sense, I don't see it in 2), namely why **all upper bounds**. How could $c$ be an upper bound, but also smaller than other upper bounds? Is not upper bound unique? (because sets are collections of unique objects, by definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set can have multiple upper bounds. Take for instance the interval $T = (0,1)$, while $S = \mathbb{R}$. Then 1 is an upper bound for $T$, but for instance 2 is also an upper bound. Actually, all $M \geq 1$ are an upper bound of $T$.

Now, the supremum of $T$ is the *smallest* upper bound of the set $T$, which in the example above is 1. Item (2) of the definition is used to guarantee this: it says that c should be less than any other upper bound of $T$.

Comment: Thank you, now I see I overlooked "An upper bound for T (in S) is an element **M ∈ S**". Makes sense now.